# Independent elements in Unity application

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, blender

Hello I would like to create an android application where the cube will be rotated and user can select any numer of cube walls. I want to use the Unity 3d to application and Blender program to create the cube. I don’t know how to make independent sides of the cube.

I mean… For example We have a dice and the walls are numbered from 1 to 6. As a user for example, I want to mark walls 2 and 4. And I also want walls 2 and 4 to turn orange when pressed on the phone.

And my problem is that I don’t know what to do to make this walls independent of the entire body. So that when you press any side of the cube, only this side will change the color, not the whole cube.

Edit:
Sorry for my English. Maybe I can show my problem in a picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmTeQ.png)

Comment: Your question is pretty vague

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: You can do like @WojtekPojda says with the quads, that's a good way of approaching this problem. Another solution is to make the mesh as you say in Blender, in such a way that it has individual sub-meshes (the walls) then you could see if the user selected one of the sub-meshes and change its material (being that each sub-mesh has a different material).

Comment: I think these meshs are my solution to the problem. Can I divide the object into a meshs that I downloaded as a ready asset?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use cube, you can write a custom shader that will change only one wall at a time.

You can also use 6 quads that you child to a single object and rotate so the result looks like a cube. Now you have 6 individual objects and you can detect clicks on each separately.

Comment: This task is only for learning. Exactly, I have to separate the elements I selected in the existing object (made in a blender). The cube was just an example to make it easier for me to understand this task and easier explain it in the question.

To sum up, I want to make the meshs independent (in the example with the cube I meant sides of the cube) from the entire object which is made in Blender.